# Difference between VBA for Excel 2003 running on Windows 10 and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2003

Okay, I have an oddly specific situation: I made a bunch of macros and Visual Basic code in an Excel 2003 Spreadsheet running on Windows 7. The product has been working perfectly for one and a half years and the client was satisfied. Recently, a new employee has been employed and they prefer to work on a Windows 10 running computer. Said computer has MS Excel 2003 and when they open the same Spreadsheet it works fine. Here's the twist: after that the computer working on Windows 7 cannot open the same product (Error:After allowing macros on startup the file crashes and needs to be either closed or troubleshooted online). The question is: is there a difference between how Windows 10 reacts to the Spreadsheet and how Windows 7 reacts to the Spreadsheet?

Comment: Well what in particular is your macro doing? I ask because I know Windows 10 introduced DPI awareness so if you have forms that may get affected

Comment: What's the startup macro doing?

Comment: It visualizes a form that acts as a navigation bar and can filter one or two sheets. And I have other two forms that are used to add rows to two of the sheets. And the last thing I have is a "number to words code". Everything else is just vlookups and such.

Comment: I was kind of hoping to see the code, but anyway... FYI Office 2003 dates back to the golden years of WinXP, has been officially out of support since April 8, 2014, and runs VBA6 which is 32-bit only (64-bit support was added in VBA7 in Office 2007, itself out of support since October 2017)... Win7 has been on extended support since 2015, ending Jan 14, 2020.